# How to make this math use two places of the decimal?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have this code here for monitoring status of a transfer of a byte array.  Problem is it always ends up a whole number.  I update a table in a DB every 10% so knowing when it is exactly 10.00% is important, otherwise hundreds of DB calls can happen every 10%.

Any ideas? I suck at math :)

```
double percentageComplete = 0;
percentageComplete = (int)(totalReadCount / (double)fileSize * 100);
```

Comment: Well it appears you are casting the result to an `int` remove the cast.

Comment: integers do not have decimals. Cast totalReadCount as double as well, and you're set.

Comment: Note, it may *never* turn out to be **exactly** a multiple of 10%, even if we ignore rounding issues....

Comment: It will only ever be exactly 10% if `fileSize` is a multiple of 10. And even then `totalReadCount` might jump over that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the cast, you have this:

`percentageComplete = (int)(totalReadCount / (double)fileSize * 100);`

Change it to this:

`percentageComplete = (totalReadCount / (double)fileSize * 100);`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider a different method of updating your database.  Testing for when a number is exactly "10%" or "10.00%" is not reliable.

Instead, test for when it is > that percentage, and then set a flag to indicate that you have done the database update for that percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you cast it to (int) after you calculated it? Remove the (int) cast, then it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

The below should get the result you want

```
percentageComplete = (totalReadCount / (double)fileSize * 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are casting your `double` to an `int`, so of course your result will be an integer, integer which cuts the trailing decimals. So if you have `double` equal to 8.9 will get truncated to 8 as well as 8.1 will get truncated to 8.
So both if your 10% is near 9, your 10% will be extremely inaccurate, because it got cut off to 8.

For "exact" 10% ,  bytes can not be split , so an approximation is the best you can get.

A file 11,111 bytes long will have 111,11 bytes as 10%, but computers read whole bytes, just as if you have 11.111 people, you can't take the exact 10%, because splitting a person to take a 0.11% of a person  + 111 people is not an option.

So you take the best approximation through rounding.

```
int fileSize10p = Math.Round((double)fileSize / 10.0); //10% of file size

if(fileSize10p ==  totalReadCount){
  //do something
}
```

Comment: I ended up using 'percentageComplete = (float)Math.Round(percentageComplete, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
if (percentageComplete == 10.00)
                                {
                                    ws_InsertProgress.InsertProgressService(smGuid.ToString(), 10.0);
                                }
if (percentageComplete == 20.00)
                                {
                                    ws_InsertProgress.InsertProgressService(smGuid.ToString(), 20.0);
                                }'
etc... keep in mind i am chunking the bytes by 49152, not reading the whole file.